# Arrays: counting down and up

Tags: arrays, function, conditional-statements, sum

I am trying to build a function which takes three arguments (starting number, ending number, and a step.

So:
`console.log(range(1, 10)); // → [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] console.log(range(5, 2, -1)); // → [5, 4, 3, 2]`

Then I need to build another function which finds the sum of these arrays.

```
   `console.log(sum(range(1, 10)));
       // → 55 `
```

Please see below code, I have built it successfully for cases which are positive. Though, it does not work with a negative step. I have a feeling that a conditional argument is needed, if (step <= -1), however I am not entirely sure how to implement this.

```
     var range = function (start, end, step) {
         var arr = [];
         for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
         arr.push(i);
         }
         return arr;
         }
      var sum = function (arr) {
         var total = 0;
         for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
         total += arr[i];
         }
         console.log(total);
         }
```

Comment: If step<0 then do the downwards loop, if step>0 then do the upwards loop, else complain that the step size isn't allowed to be 0. You would use `i += step` in either loop, not `i++`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement the `range()` function using a loop that `starts` at the start number and ends at the `end` number with the specified `step`. The loop should push each number to an array until the end number is reached.

Here's an implementation of the `range()` function:

```js
function range(start, end, step = 1) {
  const result = [];
  if (step > 0) {
    for (let i = start; i <= end; i += step) {
      result.push(i);
    }
  } else {
    for (let i = start; i >= end; i += step) {
      result.push(i);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

The `sum()` function can simply use the `reduce()` method to sum up the elements in the array returned by `range()`.

```js
function sum(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0);
}
```

Test Cases:

```js
console.log(range(1, 10)); // → [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
console.log(range(5, 2, -1)); // → [5, 4, 3, 2]
console.log(sum(range(1, 10))); // → 55
```